# JPA sequence skipping values

Tags: java, jpa, db2, websphere, jpa-2.0

I am using Open JPA 2.0, WebSphere V8 and database is DB2 V10.

Created sequence using below syntax

> CREATE SEQUENCE "MYSCHEMA"."SEQ_TABLEA" AS INTEGER  START WITH 1
>   INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1000 MAXVALUE 2147483647 NO CYCLE CACHE 100
>   ORDER;

My Entity class definition uses sequence as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MYSCHEMA.SEQ_TABLEA")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TABLEA_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="MYSCHEMA.SEQ_TABLEA")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TABLEA_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer myId;

    ..
```

After multiple inserts to TABLEA over 3 to 4 days, I find that sequence number has skipped many values. Inserts with sequence created are like 1,2,3,100,101,102,103,104,105,200,201,202,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,400,.. and so on

Any view on what is going wrong?
I did not find any error while inserting, neither the DB was bounced during this period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the allocation size on the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation.  This specifies the amount to increment when allocating sequence numbers.

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="TABLEA_ID_GENERATOR", 
  sequenceName="MYSCHEMA.SEQ_TABLEA", allocationSize=1)
```

[Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#allocationSize%28%29)

[Good Article on Sequences in JPA](http://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2010/04/note-on-allocationsize-parameter-of.html)

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realized my example had it set to 1000, try updated.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much normal behavior. The Sequencer will pre-fetch/pre-resevre an interval of values (and save the interval params in the db), but then for some reason he'll not end up actually using (saving entities) for all of those values. Later when it gets to the last value of said interval, it will create a new one, without caring/re-checking if all values from previous interval have been used up or not.

Comment: thanks for response. I need sequence to increment by 1 only. So does this mean, I should reduce the Cache to lower value or 0?

Comment: Well, yes you can, but I'm not sure this is the main intended purpose of the Sequencer. I think its main purpose is to give you better performance when using it to auto-generate ids, in the sense where the only guarantee is that each generated id is unique, not that they are incremental. That's why the sequencer does prefetch intervals of ids (it's clearly faster that to execute db queries for each one, one at a time) but doesn't really guarantee that the ids will be consecutive. You can implement your own sequencer to only have consecutive (no gaps) auto-generated ids in the database.